# Babel config file giving me an error with my tests

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I am currently facing an issue while running my tests using Jest, where I encounter an error related to `babelrc`. The error message is as follows:

`Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.`

Any insight on how can I fix this error?

Here is the configuration I have used for my Babel setup:

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv',
        {
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: '.env',
          blacklist: null,
          whitelist: null,
          safe: false,
          allowUndefined: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you post your jest.config file?